# java compiler options. -J?

Tags: javac

I want to know how do we use javac -J javaoption ? What is the purpose and how can i use this option during compile time ? I have gone through the documentation for javac -J option but do not quite follow the explanation there.

> Passes the argument javaoption directly through to the Java interpreter. For example: -J-Xmx32m. javaoption should not contain spaces; if multiple arguments must be passed to the interpreter, use multiple -J options. Java 1.1 and later.

Answer (score 5):

`javac` is itself written in Java. Thus, it provides an option to allow you to specify how `javac` itself is run (as a Java program), just like any other Java program would.

Comment: This sounds right. For instance . . . if for some reason the program you're compiling is so unbelievably large that it causes the compiler to run out of heap or stack space, you could use the -J options to run `javac` on a JVM that has been allotted more memory.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it the following way. Java applications are not executed directly, but are interpreted in a virtual machine, hence JVM. The options you normally pass to `javac` govern restrictions and options for your applications running in the JVM.

However, the JVM **itself** is also an application, a native one, which has its own options, which are set via the `-J-*` flags.

So the normal (including non-standard options) options tell the JVM how to configure and restrict **your** java code, and the `-J-*` tell the JVM how to behave **itself**.

You most probably will never need to set these options.

Comment: Can i pass a variable flag value to JVM using this -J option ? what are the different javaOptions that can be used with -J

Comment: `javac` is executed by `java`, so any [`java` options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/java.html) should be passable via `-J-*` to the `java` launcher which executes `javac`.